# How to convert a number to string in coffeescript?

Tags: string, coffeescript

Given a number

n = 42

What is the best way to convert it into a string?

```
s = String(n)
```

or

```
s = ''+n
```

or any better suggestion?

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of "best"?

Comment: I mean the 'natural' or 'obvious' or 'standard' way. E.g. in python it would be `str(n)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[String interpolation](http://coffeescript.org/#strings) might be the most natural approach in CoffeeScript:

```
s = "#{n}" # Just `'' + n` in disguise.
```

That might leave people wondering what you're doing though.

Comment: this is effectively the same as `'' + n` but looks quite explicit :-) (which is also the most efficient version [see this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19990524/2297345)

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way would be:

```
(10).toString()
// or
n = 11;
n.toString()
```

Edited to fix syntax error. `10.toString()` works in the CoffeeScript simulator but it's better to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution that is more "natural" than the other. Both are explicit and the reader will understand what it does right away in both cases.

Concerning performance, from [this test](http://jsperf.com/string-42-vs-42), the fastest is :

```
s = '' + n
```

The other method, `String(n)`, is slower.

Comment: I also added `.toString()` to [this test](http://jsperf.com/string-42-vs-42/2) which is also quite slow